# PHP and absolute path with subfolders

Tags: php, html, url

I checked lots of questions but they are not clear e naught. 
I have a website on server and path is: `C:/inetpub/website`
and in `conf.php` file i have absolute path routes:

```
define('ROOT', '');
define('CSS', ROOT . 'css/');
define('JS', ROOT . 'js/');
define('IMG', ROOT . 'images/');
define('SUBF', ROOT . 'subfolder/');
```

My index.php file in website (root) folder contains url:

```
<script src="'.JS.'jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="'.CSS.'jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="'.JS.'test.js"></script>
```

And it works but if my another file is in `C:/inetpub/website/subfilfer` then i'm struggling to access into these locations.
For example index.php source in subfolder contains:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

And it won't work because this url looking into `subfolder/js/filename`

Comment: It works with `define('ROOT', '/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');` I'm not sure if is right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define('CSS', $root . '/css/');
define('JS', $root . '/js/');
define('IMG', $root . '/images/');
define('SUBF', $root . '/subfolder/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `define('ROOT', '');` to `define('ROOT', '/');`

Comment: Then my main `index.php` in `ROOT` folder trying to pick the file from `<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` C:/inetpub but not from /website

Answer (score 0):

maybe  try to use magic constant

`__DIR__`

`__DIR__` always  give  you current  dir , so maybe  instead of ROOT use  `__DIR__`

It's  better this  way , becouse if you use ROOT and, for example you'll move your  site to  subfolder  then all aths  will be mesed up

Comment: declare ('ROOT', __DIR__); you mean?